# What does setting a class/module name before a variable definition do in Perl?

Tags: perl

Whilst working with the `Net::SIP` module I noticed in some of the functions there is code that defines the class of an argument. For example:

```
sub can_deliver_to {
    my Net::SIP::Leg $self = shift;
    [...]
    return 1;
}
```

What purpose does specifying `Net::SIP::Leg` have on defining `$self`? Is it just syntactic sugar to aid the developer in knowing what type of variable `$self` should be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It provokes a compile time error, in cases the structure/object is accessed in some invalid way.

See https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html

> ```
> my VARLIST
> my TYPE VARLIST
> my VARLIST : ATTRS
> my TYPE VARLIST : ATTRS
> ```
>
> A `my` declares the listed variables to be local (lexically) to the enclosing block, file, or eval. If more than one variable is listed, the list must be placed in parentheses.
>
> The exact semantics and interface of TYPE and ATTRS are still evolving. TYPE may be a bareword, a constant declared with `use constant` , or `__PACKAGE__`. It is currently bound to the use of the `fields` pragma, and attributes are handled using the `attributes` pragma, or starting from Perl 5.8.0 also via the `Attribute::Handlers` module.

And if you jump at the documentation on `fields` at https://perldoc.perl.org/fields.html you get this example:

```
{
    package Foo;
    use fields qw(foo bar _Foo_private);
    sub new {
        my Foo $self = shift;
        unless (ref $self) {
            $self = fields::new($self);
            $self->{_Foo_private} = "this is Foo's secret";
        }
        $self->{foo} = 10;
        $self->{bar} = 20;
        return $self;
    }
}
my $var = Foo->new;
$var->{foo} = 42;

# this will generate a run-time error
$var->{zap} = 42;

# this will generate a compile-time error
my Foo $foo = Foo->new;
$foo->{zap} = 24;
```